# AWS Cloudfront Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have an AWS Cloudfront Distribution set up and I'm making a request to one of my endpoints in API Gateway which is linked as a behavior on the distribution. I'm getting a CloudFront Error that says

```js
{"exception": "'str' object has no attribute 'values'"}
```

I don't have any CloudFront logs to view so I can't really diagnose why this is happening. Anyone else receive this error before and know what to do?

Comment: It appears you are not sending the request in the proper format. Maybe make sure it is sending a JSON object with proper values for its 'values' attribute.

Comment: I just tried the request from postman, and I am getting the same response. Surely Postman can't be formatting the request incorrectly?

Comment: It will format the request in whatever way you configure it to. Check the Cloudfront documentation and make sure you're doing it right.